# Render view files on Yii framework

Tags: php, templates, yii, renderpartial

I have 2 models suppose A and B which contain two separate forms. I want to show the content of form B on the view page of model A. So how to render the content of B on A. Any help on this will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the B model to the view of the A model, if you're using the code generated by Yii's CRUD for example in the AController file you can modify it into this:

```
public function actionView() 
{
  $BModel = B::model()->findAll();

  $this->render('view',array(
    'model'=>$this->loadModel(),
    'othermodel'=>$BModel,
  ));
}
```

after adding the 'othermodel' into the view function, you should be able to access $othermodel in the view.php file

Comment: Ya I am using this public function actionView($id)
  {
    $a = $this->loadModel($id);
    $b = $this->newb($a);
    if(isset($_POST['b'])){
     $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$this->loadModel(),
      'b' => $b,
      ));
    }
    else{
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model' => $a,
      'b' => $b,
    ));
    }
  }
 But cant render the a and b in a same view

Comment: what's the content of your view.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a renderPartial of the view of model B into the view of model A:

```
// This is _formA
...
$modelB = new ModelB();
echo $this->renderPartial('/modelB/_formB',array('model'=>$modelB));
...
```